# How to make Android HomeScreen Widget Appear on 4.2.x

Tags: android, android-appwidget

[this](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzLZzIYTIXweckYxdVgwSDlFZ2c&usp=sharing) is a link to a simple android homescreen widget. I was able to do it after reading some tutorials online. However, The Homescreen widget shows on devices less than 4.2 but it does not appear on my 4.2.2 or any 4.2.x. I need help on what to do to make this work.